# New user on computer?

Tags: windows-7, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo computer, windows 7. When I opened up my computer this morning, there was a new user called lenovo_tmp_keys_vamn? Should I be worried?

Comment: Depends; did you install new software?

Comment: Looks very suspicious to me

Comment: @Alex - It's 100% harmless.  Nvidia software creates a service account to do something similar.

Comment: @Ramhound I know that some software creating new user accounts(QuickBook, TeamViewer), but usually such accounts created as disabled for login, so shouldn't appear on logon screen especially with  such weird account name...

Comment: @Alex - The same is the case with this username, as per my answer, this user is harmless.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I be worried?

You should absolutely not be worried.  The user is connected to the `ThinkVantage Service Update` you have running on your system.

Since you can uninstall the service and delete the user in question, provided you are the administrator of the device if you are worried about the user existence. 
 Since the service serves absolutely no real purpose for a normal user, I highly encourage you to uninstall the useless OEM software**, provided you have the authorization to do so.

> The TVSU service creates a temporary admin account with a random name
>   and random password, and uses it to do the installations on behalf of
>   the limited user.  This is the only time the account is created.  The
>   account is not created when an admin user does updates, because the
>   admin user already has the permissions needed to do installations.
>
> The account is supposed to be deleted after the TVSU session finishes, but I'm aware of a case where this doesn't happen and the account stays around.  However there isn't any security risk to this because both the account and password are random and not known by anything except the specific TVSU process that created them, and this process ended the last time TVSU was closed.  You can safely ignore the account, delete the account, or else it should be deleted the next time TVSU is run.

TVSU is supposed to delete the user after the installation is performed, if the installation was interrupted, then the removal of the user didn't happen.  If this is not your personal machine, you shouldn't uninstall the service, since the service being installed is intentional.

[tvsu_tmp_ in my local user](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Pre-Installed-Lenovo-Software/tvsu-tmp-in-my-local-user/td-p/1225303)

Answer (score -1):

Depending on known information, it seems that this user account is related to ThinkVantage Service Update which provided by Lenovo. It is suggested contacting Lenovo directly to confirm. If it is TVSU service, you should absolutely not be worried.